# To create a grid using font awesome icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]As shown in image i want to create that type of grid using font awesome icons.I write code for that but i didn't get output my expectation want to get output as shown in image.What i do for  that?

```
<div class="container">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 style="color:#0E57A4;"><center>24X7 Emergency Responce</center></h1><br><br>
            </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="media-left"> <i class="fa fa-home fa-5x"></i>
                             </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 style="color:#0e57a4;">Resenditial Services</h4>
                                <p class="para">Steamatic knows that the health and safety of your family is your first concern. Our restoration and cleaning services are all about providing you with the healthiest indoor environment possible.</p>
                            </div>

                     </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: The image is missing

Comment: check it i upload image.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly adjusted your HTML structure (added a container around media-left and media-body) and added a CSS class to position those two elements correctly.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 style="color:#0E57A4;">
      <center>24X7 Emergency Responce</center>
    </h1><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class=" flex">
        <div class="media-left"> <i class="fa fa-home fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 style="color:#0e57a4;">Resenditial Services</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="para">Steamatic knows that the health and safety of your family is your first concern. Our restoration and cleaning services are all about providing you with the healthiest indoor environment possible.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this HTML code, hope this will help you.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 style="color:#0E57A4;"><center>24X7 Emergency Responce</center></h1><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="media-left"> <i class="fa fa-home fa-5x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
          <h4 style="color:#0e57a4;">Resenditial Services</h4>
          <p class="para">Steamatic knows that the health and safety of your family is your first concern. Our restoration and cleaning services are all about providing you with the healthiest indoor environment possible.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="media-left"> <i class="fa fa-home fa-5x"></i>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
           <h4 style="color:#0e57a4;">Resenditial Services</h4>
           <p class="para">Steamatic knows that the health and safety of your family is your first concern. Our restoration and cleaning services are all about providing you with the healthiest indoor environment possible.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```